# How to uncompress multiple Zlib Archives with one comand

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, command, archive

I have >200 .zlib Archives and I want to uncompress them using one command in Linux console. I just cant get the command right. maybe somone can help me:

```
for z in *.zlib; do; zlib-flate -uncompress < $z > $z ; done
```

When I run this command every file is empty. I don't really care about the output-filename, so this could be just a counter or a added string for example.
Many thanks!

Comment: Why is the in file and outfile the same name?

Comment: I hope you have backup of these archives. Or did the syntax error save the day? My point is your command with proper syntax (i.e. without `;` after `do`) [empties the files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/186126/108618). Don't run it and check the sizes of the files.

Comment: @KevinO Like I mentioned: the output-filename does not matter to me, I just need the uncompressed data

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Yes I have a backup, don't worry haha. But thanks for the advice. I'm  new to bash commands...

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Yes I have a backup, don't worry haha. But thanks for the advice. I'm  new to bash commands...

Comment: I think my point, and I believe what @KamilMaciorowski was also suggesting, is that if you attempt to write to the same file that you read, bad things are likely to happen. You might be able to do `zlib-flag -uncompress < $z > $z.unc` (and remove the `;` after the `do`). The operation should be against actual compressed files with expected sizes, of course.

Comment: Thanks! now it's working, but somehow the resulting files are smaller than the original zlib archives. But I think thats another problem and has nothing todo with the command

Comment: The way the shell works is that command-line redirection (`<$z >$z`) is handled by the parent shell, before `zlib-flate` even starts. `>%z` opens the file for writing, at byte 0. Do all the archives contain the same filenames? Different filenames?

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add new information, properly formatted. Information added via comments is hard for you to format, hard for us to read and ignored by future readers. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our uplink to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: Read `man gzip gunzip`. They'd better tools

Comment: have you try `zlib-flate -uncompress *.zlib`?

Answer (score 0):

what happened is is the > part executes first and makes a new empty file to collect the output, but this process destroys the intended input data.

To fix: explicitly use a different file-name for the output.

```
for z in *.zlib; do; zlib-flate -uncompress < "$z" > "${z%.zlib}" ; done
```

here `"${z%.zlib}"` trims the `.zlib` off the end of the filenames.